# Groupings for N items

Tags: combinatorics

For $n = 3$, there's 1 group of 3 or 3 groups of 1, or a group of 2 and a group of 1, for a total of 3 different "groupings".

for $n = 2$, there's 2 "groupings": 1 group of 2 or 2 groups of 1

I had thought that this was just the combinations of n unlabeled items into a different number of unlabeled boxes, but when I looked up "number of k-element partitions of n" here: http://www.statlect.com/subon2/compar1.htm it seems to give the answer for labeled items.

Is there a way to calculate this?  What is the correct terminology for this?  Thank You

Comment: These are called [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you cite is somewhat confusing because, in its heading, it seems to point to counting the number of number of "partitions" of a number $n$ into $k$ groups, but:

- it does not make clear from the start if it consider the groups as distinguishable or not (it does)
- it uses the word "partition" in a non-standard way: usually, to count "partitions" means that "groups" as non-distinguishable
- only in the body it's make clear that the formula found (multinomial coefficient) does not count all those "partitions", but those with fixed number of elements in each group ($k_i$)

In your case, you are counting (standard) [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). There's no simple formula for that.